# Compile directive that is injected from a JSON file AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

Hoping someone can help me with this challenge.

I request JSON data from the server using `$http.get()`;

The data from the server returns an object. One value in the object contains HTML markup. This markup is injected to the page using `<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="content" />`

Within the markup, there is a custom directive named `<poll />`

Using the standard AngularJS directive structure, it does not pick up the directive and link it.

How can I compile this HTML once retrieved from the server and call the link function on the directive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `$compile` service is what you want.](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/docs/api/ng/service/$compile)

The `$compile` service can be injected into a controller or directive and invoked on a template. It will return a linking function which you can call, passing in the scope that you want to link.

Here's an example:

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('MainCtrl', function ($compile, $rootScope) {
  var template = '<special-directive prop="myProp"> </special-directive>';
  var scope = $rootScope.$new();
  var top = document.getElementById('top');
  scope.myProp = 'Say hello to your mother for me';
  top.innerHTML = template;
  
  $compile(top)(scope);
})

angular.module('app').directive('specialDirective', function () {
 return {
      scope:{ prop: '=' },
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function (scope, ele) {
        var html = 'Hello from the special directive<br/><br/>' + scope.prop;
        ele.html(html);
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="top"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've been looking into the $compile function but cannot get it to work :(

I'm currently using `$scope.content = $compile($scope.tip.data.Node.body);` then <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="content" />` but nothing shows up in the template

Comment: Please see the snippet above.