# AngularJS directive in $http json response

Tags: angularjs, compilation, angularjs-directive

I try the same thing as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966790/compile-directive-that-is-injected-from-a-json-file-angularjs)

I retrieve with Ajax server Data which Json contains the markup with a directive and trying to use $compile to fire up this one but at this point without any luck

here is my controller where I try use `$compile`

```
angular.module('blancAppApp')
  .controller('SlugCtrl', function ($scope, WpApi, $compile, $filter, ngProgressLite) {

    // the Content to be rendered.
   $scope.post = [];
   //loading animate starts
   ngProgressLite.start();
   loadRemoteData();

   // load remote data from the server.
   function loadRemoteData() {
   // The WpApiService returns a promise.
        WpApi.getContents()
        .then(
            function( post ) {       
                applyRemoteData( post );       
            });    
    }

     // apply the remote data to the local scope.
    function applyRemoteData( newContents ) {
        var compiled = $compile( newContents )($scope);
        console.log(compiled); // this one shows me the object then object.content contains my masonry directive
       firebug output: <div class="ng-scope">[object Object]</div>
    }



  //loading animate ends
  ngProgressLite.done();        

}).directive('compiled', function($timeout) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                compiled: '=compiled'
            },

            link: function (scope, element, attrs, $timeout) {

            element.append(scope.compiled);
        }
    };
});
```

**the directive which should be called**

```
angular.module('blancAppApp')
  .directive('masonry',  function(scope, element, attrs, $timeout) {
            console.log('asdasd');
            var container = element.querySelector('#grid');
                var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
                // options...
                itemSelector: '.masonry-brick',
                columnWidth: 200
            });



        return {
            restrict: 'E'        
        };

  });
```

**the generated view**

```
<div ng-repeat ="article in post " id="#main-content">
    <div ng-bind-html="article.content | unsafe">
        <div ng-controller="ContentCtrl">       
            {{ article.content }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Generated Markup with directive call**

```
<div id="grid" masonry="">
 <div class="masonry-brick "><img src=""... /></div>
 <div class="masonry-brick "><img src=""... /></div>
 <div class="masonry-brick "><img src=""... /></div>
</div>
```

[image]

[plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/7ur2sqeXFjqbAaFtjHVt/preview)

Answer (score 3):

You use $compile incorrectly. $compile returns "a link function which is used to bind template". So you need to call returned function. Try:

```
var compiled = $compile($scope.post)($scope);
console.log(compiled);
```

Resulting element must be then attached somewhere to DOM document for example with directive:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="plunker">
        <div data-ng-controller="SlugCtrl">
            <div id="compiled_content" data-compiled="compiled">

            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
            app.controller('SlugCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {
                $scope.some_var = 'var content';
                var template = '<div>{{some_var}}</div>';
                $scope.compiled = $compile(template)($scope);
                $scope.some_var = 'var content canged';
            }).directive('compiled', function() {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    scope: {
                        compiled: '=compiled'
                    },
                    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                        element.append(scope.compiled);
                    }
                };
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I used `element.append(scope.compiled);` and not just `{{scope.compiled}}` because compilation result is object and not a string.

Your applyRemoteData function must be like this:

```
function applyRemoteData( newContents ) {
    $scope.compiled = $compile('<div>' + newContents + '</div>')($scope);
}
```

Comment: yeah it seems is what I need but i have problems to apply on my remote data

Comment: I get `assignment to undeclared variable $compiled`

Comment: Do you get some errors in console? Also you can try to wrap your template in <div></div> so it will have only one top level element.

Comment: I've been wrapping the template no error in console using firebug, chrome. I added an update on controller because between I use  a service to get remote data